# Find a basis for kernel of T nonlinear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $T$ from $R^3$ $\to$ $R^2$ be a transformation defined as
$$T \left(\left(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{matrix}\right)\right) \to \left(\begin{matrix} xy \\ xz \end{matrix}\right)$$
Find a basis for $N(T)$ (null space/ kernel of $T$).
*Note the original request is to verify if T is linear trough the dimension theorem, so in order to do it you need to find the dimension (i.e number of basis) of $N(T)$.

My reasoning is, let $v$ be a generic vector $\left(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{matrix}\right)$ in  $R^3$ it gets transformed to the $0$ vector by $T$ in two cases
$$ v1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ r \\ s\end{matrix}\right) r,s \in R$$
This case ($v1$) is the only considered by the book.

$$ v2 = \left(\begin{matrix} h \\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right) h \in R$$
The book doesn't mention $v2$ so from there the doubt if I am wrong or what.
Now following, a basis for $v1$ can be $\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right);\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right) \rbrace$;
Same as the book which concludes that $dim(N(T)) = 2$.

Now a basis for $v2$ would be $\{\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)\}$, but why doesn't the book even consider it?

I'm stuck here, finding a basis that works for both $v1$ and $v2$ would bring me to $\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right);\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right);\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right) \rbrace$ which is a basis for $R^3$ which indeed spans $\{v1; v2\}$ but spanning all $R^3$ it goes further.

As you can see I don't have clear ideas, can someone give me some hint or tell me where I'm wrong?

Thanks

*Sorry for my english

Comment: You are correct that all vectors of the form of your $v_2$ are mapped to $0$. Can't say why your book does not consider them. After that, you should note that the image is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that it contradicts the Dimension Theorem if $T$ were linear (which of course it is not).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for answering, now one of the doubts I have is the following. How to find a basis for  $N(T)$?

Comment: $N(T)$ is not a subspace, so it doesn’t have a basis. Perhaps that is what your book was trying to do, rather clumsily and confusingly: the subspace they determine is in fact the largest (in terms of dimension) subspace contained in the nullspace.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh yes, I'm stupid, now i've just realized it thanks to you, now its more clear Thanks again